# How do I open the camera in a CCScene node in a Cocos2D application?

Tags: iphone, camera, cocos2d

I am new to Cocos2D and I can't find the way to open the camera from the library. I want to open the camera in the my game, can any one help me with with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the phrase "open the camera?"

Comment: i want to get the camera input as the sprite in my application so here i want to take photo from the camera   
thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

I guess that CCRenderTexture is what you are looking for.

Take a look at [this example](http://cocos2d-iphone.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1325/trunk/tests/RenderTextureTest.m)

Comment: is this link work for cocoas2d 0.99.5 version because it shown me  many of the error    thank you for your reply

Comment: Maybe this example just works with 1.0, but it should be easy to modify it to work with prior versions